# A problem with the solution graph appearing in the statistics tab using constraint programing in Cplex Opl Studio

Tags: ide, cplex, constraint-programming, opl

I am using CPLEX studio IDE version 22.1.1, and I am solving my problem using Constraint Programming (CP). I have a little issue with the statistics tab of my solution. There is a chart on the right side of this section presenting the objective-solution behavior vs. time. But, in the previous versions of Cplex, there used to be an option appearing by right-clicking on the chart, and we could select "see the whole chart" and we could be able to see the behavior of all solutions vs. time. In the latest version of my Cplex studio, I can see only the last part of the graph on the chart. Does anyone know how can I fix this? bests